# Understanding Template Matching in openCV

Tags: opencv

Just want to clear out my confusion. I've tested openCV template matching method to match some numbers. First I have this sequence of number 0 1 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 4 5 (after binarization probably the character width is different). How does template matching works to match number '1'? Does it;

1. slides through all the window until it found 2 matches (2 output), or
2. stop after it match the first '1', or
3. find the highest correlation between the two number '1' and choose either one.

[image: Matching Number '1']

Edited: As attached is the output. It only match one number '1' and not two '1'.

[Q] How can I detect two numbers '1' simultaneously?

Comment: you should have googled a little more...http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/template_matching/template_matching.html

Comment: Yes, I've read it before I post it here. But, when i tried on my example only one number is selected to match.

Comment: which matching method you are using?correlation?try the CV_TM_SQDIFF

Comment: I'm using CV_TM_CCORR_NORMED which will give value 1.0(highest match).

Comment: whats your output with CV_TM_SQDIFF?

Comment: very huge values (9753750) and it doesn't match anything

Comment: Does template matching finds all the possibilities of matching the '1' or it just find the highest match?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I know it's an old question but here is an answer.

When you do MatchTemplate, it will output an grayscale image. After that, you will need to do a MinMax on it. Then, you can check if there is a result in the range you are looking for. In the example below, using EmguCV (a wrapper of OpenCV in C#), I draw a rectangle around the best find (index 0 of the minValues array) only if it's below 0.75 (you can adjust this threshold for your needs).

Here is the code:

```
Image<Gray, float> result = new Image<Gray, float>(new System.Drawing.Size(nWidth, nHeight));
result = image.CurrentImage.MatchTemplate(_imageTemplate.CurrentImage, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.TM_TYPE.CV_TM_SQDIFF_NORMED);


double[] minValues;
double[] maxValues;
System.Drawing.Point[] minLocations;
System.Drawing.Point[] maxLocations;

result.MinMax(out minValues, out maxValues, out minLocations, out maxLocations);
if (minValues[0] < 0.75)
{
    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(new Point(minLocations[0].X, minLocations[0].Y), 
        new Size(_imageTemplate.CurrentImage.Width, _imageTemplate.CurrentImage.Height));
    image.CurrentImage.Draw(rect, new Bgr(0,0,255), 1);
}
else
{
    //Nothing has been found
}
```

***EDIT***

Here is an example of the output:

[image: Example of output]

Comment: Could you paste some image of what you did?

Comment: I'll edit my answer next week when I'll have the code with me